# Why is the space in this jQuery selector-expression relevant

Tags: javascript, jquery

suppose i have this HTML snippet (assume the remaining document has no other div's) :

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
     <pre>1st</pre>
</div>
```

using jQuery i would expect this piece of code ...

```
$('div:has(pre) :eq(0)').css('background-color','red');
$('div:has(pre):eq(0)').css('color','green');
```

to set the background-color to red and the color to green for the whole `<div>`.
In other words i would expect both jQuery selectors to match the same set of elements containing the single div. However the first selector only seems to match the `<pre>`, while the second selector actually matches the `<div>`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u10kyqov/5/)

Comment: FYI, jQuery has documentation about all selectors it supports: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`div:has(pre) :eq(0)` uses a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/). The other does not.

This is to match the behavior of CSS selectors.

Comment: ok, i was not aware that 'pseudoclass selectors' like :eq() behave like descendat selectors as well ! thank you !

Comment: @AndréR.: The space is the descendant selector. `:eq` does not behave like anything. It's just another selector. `:eq` is simply the short form of `*:eq`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes *"Pseudo-classes are allowed anywhere in sequences of simple selectors, after the leading type selector or universal selector (possibly omitted)."*

Comment: @Felix Kling ... i'm aware that :eq() is not a descendant selector itself ;-) ... maybe i should have said 'in the context of a descendant selector' ?

Answer (score 4):

In CSS selectors, a space means "descendant of".  So `div p` would mean "all `<p>` tags that are descendantof a `<div>`.

When you do `'div:has(pre):eq(0)'`, you are applying the `:has` and `:eq` to the `div` selector, so you will find the 1st `<div>` that has a `<pre>` inside.

`'div:has(pre) :eq(0)'` on the other hand will find the 1st child of any `<div>` that has a `<pre>` inside.

Comment: Much better explanation imo.

Comment: @Andy, I agree, this should have gotten more upvotes. Another case of FGITW.